# yii2 captcha always return incorrect

Tags: php, yii2, captcha

My Controller and it always gives incorrect captcha. Please any one help me.

when the code runs to $model->validate(), the captcha verify returns true.
but after that, in the process of $model->save(), the captcha is changed. and validate return false.

```
class SiteController extends Controller {

public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout',
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actions() {
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            //'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
        ],
    ];
}
```

this is my model

```
    public static function tableName() {
    return 'users';

public function rules() {
    return [
        ["captcha",'captcha']
    ];

}
```

Here is my user controller where i save the data

```
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

class UserController extends Controller {

public function behaviors() {
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionCreate() {
       $model = new Users();
       $userLoginExist = Yii::$app->user->identity;
       if(!$userLoginExist) {
           if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
               if ($model->validate()&& $model->save()) {
               }
           }
       }
}
```

}

Comment: update your question and add the related  action too..

Comment: If i remove "$model->validate()"  then its working because of it is not validate so.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you don't load the values returned  by post  inside the (new) model try using   (instead of  `if ($model->validate()&& $model->save()) {`)

```
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

  }
```

Comment: why not use $model->validate()??

Comment: because  .. validate() public method  Performs the data validation.
This method executes the validation rules applicable to the current scenario.. but don't load the data in the model  .. you must load the values if you want save them ..   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#validate()-detail

Answer (score 0):

Consider this part of your code

```
public function actionCreate() {
       $model = new Users();
       $userLoginExist = Yii::$app->user->identity;
       if(!$userLoginExist) {
           if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
               if ($model->validate()&& $model->save()) {
               }
           }
       }
}
```

if you’ve already validated, just call save(false) to skip the repeated validation check.

So it should be like

```
public function actionCreate() {
       $model = new Users();
       $userLoginExist = Yii::$app->user->identity;
       if(!$userLoginExist) {
           if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
               if ($model->validate()&& $model->save(false)) {
               }
           }
       }
}
```